# How do I use this try catch method?

Tags: java

I'm in intro to java. The program is supposed to be able to ask for 10 integers. It then labels the integers as strings. Then I'm supposed to use the parseInt method to convert the string into an Int. I'm also supposed to throw in a try catch loop so if someone enters anything other than an integer it prints an invalid statement. The try catch statement is supposed to tell the user which integer they entered incorrectly and ask them to reenter it.

heres what the output SHOULD look like

> Welcome to Minilab 10 – Exceptions.
>   Enter ten integers.
>   Integer #1: 50
>   Integer #2: 25
>   Integer #3: 37
>   Integer #4: 98
>   Integer #5: 77
>   Integer #6: 41
>   Integer #7: 44
>   Integer #8: 42
>   Integer #9: 29
>   Integer #10: z
>   z is not an integer.  Please enter integer #10 again: 75
>
> You entered 50 25 37 98 77 41 44 42 29 75
>   The total of the integers entered was: 518
>
> Thank you for using the Exceptions program.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Exceptions10

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        String string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7,     string8, string9, string10;
        int Int1, Int2, Int3, Int4, Int5, Int6, Int7, Int8, Int9, Int10,     Average;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Welcome to Minilab 10 -Exceptions");

    System.out.print("\n\nEnter 10 Integers");

    System.out.print("\n\nInteger 1: ");
    string1 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 2: ");
    string2 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 3: ");
    string3 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 4: ");
    string4 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 5: ");
    string5 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 6: ");
    string6 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 7: ");
    string7 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 8: ");
    string8 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 9: ");
    string9 = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Integer 10: ");
    string10 = scan.next();



    try
    {
    Int1 = Integer.parseInt(string1);
    Int2 = Integer.parseInt(string2);
    Int3 = Integer.parseInt(string3);
    Int4 = Integer.parseInt(string4);
    Int5 = Integer.parseInt(string5);
    Int6 = Integer.parseInt(string6);
    Int7 = Integer.parseInt(string7);
    Int8 = Integer.parseInt(string8);
    Int9 = Integer.parseInt(string9);
    Int10 = Integer.parseInt(string10);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
            System.out.println("Integer---  is not an integer. Please enter integer--- again: ");
    }


    int [] value = {Int1, Int2, Int3, Int4, Int5, Int6, Int7, Int8, Int9,     Int10};

    System.out.print("\nYou entered: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.print(value[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.print("\n\n");

        Average = (Int1 + Int2 + Int3 + Int4 + Int5 + Int6 + Int7 + Int8 + Int9     + Int10)/value.length;

        System.out.print("The average of the integers is " + Average +              "\n\n");


    }
}
```

My problem is my try catch statement. I don't know where or how to put it.

Comment: your current try/catch block will handle any number conversion that is not a number. if you want to catch each one individually and loop until correct, you will need to put a try/catch around each `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: I'd highly suggest to create a simple for loop and using a String array to store the strings. It makes your code way more compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method will attempt to parse the String as an int and keep requesting the input until it can be done.

```
public static int parse(String str, int number){
    while(true){
        try{
            // Attempt to parse it as an int
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        catch(Exception e){
            // Request the input again
            System.out.println("Integer #" + number + " was entered incorrectly, please enter it again: ");
            str = scan.next();
        }
    }
    return 0; // Stop compiler from complaining about no return statement
}
```

If you were to put the input into a list, then you could loop through the list, calling this method each time. This would also make the code more compact and maintainable.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we could check the inputting once it was inputted.
We just use a ten times loop as `Do..while`, and we can reduce the counter after a valid inputting. If the inputting is not valid, just continue the loop with out as:

```
do{
    try{
        System.out.print("\n\nInteger "+counter+": ");
        Int[counter] = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
        counter++;
    }
    catch{
        continue;
    }
}while(counter>10);
```

We also can applied the idea to the last part of your code. Just need to change the conditions of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I'd highly suggest using an array. That way you can do everything fairly simple in *one* for loop, instead of creating ten strings and ten integers (just imagine if you were asked to do this for 100 strings).

```
String input;
int[] integers = new int[10];
boolean parsed;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to Minilab 10: Exceptions");
System.out.println("Enter 10 Integers");

for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Integer " + (i+1) + ": ");
    input = scan.next();
    parsed = false;
    while (!parsed) {
        try {
            integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
            parsed = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Input " + (i+1) + " is not an integer. Please enter it again: ");
            input = scan.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you have chose to refactor his code, why is inputs an array. The value is no longer needed after it is parsed.

Comment: is that not what your integer array is for.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program will need to re-prompt the user if they enter an invalid number, you will want your prompt to exist within a loop that will break once a correct number is entered.

```
    int[] ints = new int[10];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ints.length) {
        int prettyInt = i + 1;
        System.out.print("Integer " + prettyInt + ": ");
        try {
            ints[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++; // continue to next int
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Integer " + scanner.next()
                    + " is not an integer. Please enter integer " + prettyInt + " again: ");
        }
    }
```